# How to read cookie which is already set in browser using hapi.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, cookies, hapi.js

I do know how to write and then read the cookie using hapi.js. But my problem is I would like to know how to read the cookie which is set already in browser (by third party api) using hapi.js

Any help is appreciated

Comment: You cannot read a cookie set by another domain. This is a security by design approach.

Comment: same as @gokcand. But if you want same cookie to be passed to another domain you can put a proxy which redirects all request to domain on which cookie is set to domain you want cookie to be forwarded.

Answer (score 3):

Use `Request.state.<cookie-name>`.

Below is the link to Hapi.js documentation - https://hapijs.com/api#request.state

Comment: I used already. But it is not giving me cookie. If I set cookie then I can able to read cookie, if not I cant able to read it

Comment: Check the origin of the cookie being set from browser console.